# GDB: What is the purpose of #'s in assembly output?

Tags: assembly, gdb

While attempting to play around with GDB, I noticed that some assembly instructions are suffixed with #(hex). Here is an example:

```
0x7ffff1f0f0d6 <inflate+5158>   mov    %rax,0x18(%r13)
0x7ffff1f0f0da <inflate+5162>   jmpq   0x7ffff1f0e3bf <inflate+1807>
0x7ffff1f0f0df <inflate+5167>   lea    0x7bca(%rip),%rsi        # 0x7ffff1f16cb0
0x7ffff1f0f0e6 <inflate+5174>   movl   $0x1d,0x0(%r13)
0x7ffff1f0f0ee <inflate+5182>   mov    %rsi,0x30(%rbp)
```

What is the meaning of the part that says `# 0xfffff1f16cb0`? It looks like a comment of some kind, but what information is it trying to convey?

Extra information:
This is a disassembly of an x86_64 application without debugging symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just friendly service from your disassembler, it is not there in the machine code. `gdb` calculates the actual address for you, so you don't have to do that manually. In your example `0x7bca(%rip)` the value of `%rip` is `0x7ffff1f0f0e6` (the address of the following instruction) and adding `0x7bca` to that gives `0x7ffff1f16cb0` which is the value printed.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was a GDB-ism. At first, I had only seen it on instructions that used the %mmx registers. But checking the %mmx register didn't show that value. I guess it was the other register I should have been looking at!

Comment: That is, %xmm registers*

Comment: That's very useful to know. At least for me, I would like to know sometimes the absolute address after relocation and loading.